# rails get data from coffee to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have some controller code like this to update the workorder.wostatus_id field.

```
def changestatus
 @workorder = Workorder.find(params[:id])
 @workorder.update_attributes(params[:wostatus_id])
 render nothing: true
end
```

And the coffee script that ends up executing changestatus:

```
  receive: (event, ui) ->
    alert $(ui.item).attr('change_url')
    alert $(this).data('wostatus-id')
    $.ajax
      type: 'PUT'
      url: "http://localhost:5000/workorders/13/changestatus"
      data:
        wostatus_id: 3
```

I have hard coded the url and wostatus_id while trying to get this working.

But, the following line isn't getting the 3 from the coffee:

```
    @workorder.update_attributes(params[:wostatus_id])
```

If I hard code the line to this, it works to update the wostatus to 3:

```
@workorder.update_attribute :wostatus_id, '4'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of your CoffeeScript:

```
data:
  wostatus_id: 3
```

Should give you a `params` that looks like this:

```
{ :wostatus_id => 3 }
```

So when you say:

```
@workorder.update_attributes(params[:wostatus_id])
```

you're really saying:

```
@workorder.update_attributes(3)
```

and that doesn't really make much sense. You need to give `update_attributes` a key and a value:

```
@workorder.update_attributes(:wostatus_id => params[:wostatus_id])
```